# when I try to update a row of my listview, always the affect row is the last row

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, onclicklistener

Good day,
My app is a simple memo app.

here is my **customAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
private ArrayList<MemoDetails> mMemos = new ArrayList<MemoDetails>();
private Context mContext;
boolean isDeleteMode = false;

private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MemoListActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<MemoDetails> memos) {

    mMemos = memos;
    mContext = mainActivity;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mMemos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mMemos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tViewMemoTitle;
    TextView tViewMemoCreatedDate;
    TextView tViewMemoAlarmedDate;
    CheckBox cb;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;       
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);

    holder.tViewMemoTitle=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.memo_list_title);      
    holder.tViewMemoCreatedDate=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.memo_list_created_date);
    holder.tViewMemoAlarmedDate=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.memo_list_alarmed_date);
    holder.cb=(CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

    final MemoDetails memo = getDetails(position);

    holder.tViewMemoTitle.setText(memo.getmMemoTitle());     
    holder.tViewMemoCreatedDate.setText("Created Date : " + memo.getmCreatedDate());
    holder.tViewMemoAlarmedDate.setText("Alarm Date : " + memo.getmAlarmedDate() + " " + memo.getmAlarmed());

    if(isDeleteMode) {
        holder.cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor c=SplashActivity.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM memos WHERE id='"+memo.getmMemoId()+"'", null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                SplashActivity.db.execSQL("UPDATE memos SET "
                        + "alarmed='1' WHERE "
                        + "id = '" + memo.getmMemoId() + "'" );
                memo.setmAlarmed("1");
                MemoListActivity.mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }); 


    holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    holder.cb.setTag(position);
    holder.cb.setChecked(memo.mCheckBox);

    return rowView;
}

private MemoDetails getDetails(int position) {
    return ((MemoDetails) getItem(position));
}

public ArrayList<MemoDetails> getBox() {
    ArrayList<MemoDetails> box = new ArrayList<MemoDetails>();
    for (MemoDetails memo : mMemos) {
        if (memo.mCheckBox)
            box.add(memo);
    }
    return box;
}

private OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        getDetails((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).mCheckBox = isChecked;
    }
};
```

}

each of my memo has a detail of

```
alarmed = '0'
```

so when i tap specific row, it will turn to

```
alarmed = '1'
```

my problem is, whenever I tap any row in my listview,
the only affected row is the last row.

here is my **onclicklistener** part

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor c=SplashActivity.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM memos WHERE id='"+memo.getmMemoId()+"'", null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                SplashActivity.db.execSQL("UPDATE memos SET "
                        + "alarmed='1' WHERE "
                        + "id = '" + memo.getmMemoId() + "'" );
                memo.setmAlarmed("1");
                MemoListActivity.mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Code Updated**

I removed the

```
private MemoDetails memo;
```

as a global variable instantiate it inside as final

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MemoDetails memo = getDetails(position);

}
```

And it is fixed :)

Comment: try with myListView.invalidateViews();   This should be outside adapter class, give a call back to implementation class and handle the click. Now call MemoListActivity.mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as well as myListView.invalidateViews();

Comment: Why you are not using listview.SetOnItemClickListener?

Comment: Stallion, Raghavendra, sorry, I could not follow the instructions . I am new in creating customAdapter for listview.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong

```
 rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor c=SplashActivity.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM memos WHERE id='"+memo.getmMemoId()+"'", null);
                if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                    SplashActivity.db.execSQL("UPDATE memos SET "
                            + "alarmed='1' WHERE "
                            + "id = '" + memo.getmMemoId() + "'" );
                    memo.setmAlarmed("1");
                    MemoListActivity.mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

when you click on the row, you try to get the id from "memo.getmMemoId()" this is alway last object of your arrayList.

you should fetch the id from row then only it is working properly.

It is done in number of ways. if you need id, you just declare one variable "id" in the viewholder class

```
public class Holder
{
    TextView tViewMemoTitle;
    TextView tViewMemoCreatedDate;
    TextView tViewMemoAlarmedDate;
    CheckBox cb;
   String id;
}
```

Then you add the id for every row like this

```
holder.tViewMemoTitle.setText(memo.getmMemoTitle());     
    holder.tViewMemoCreatedDate.setText("Created Date : " + memo.getmCreatedDate());
    holder.tViewMemoAlarmedDate.setText("Alarm Date : " + memo.getmAlarmedDate() + " " + memo.getmAlarmed());

**holder.id=memo.getmMemoId();**
```

so then every row object having the id of object.

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=convertView;
        final CategorisedApplicationsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(view==null){
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.categorised_apps_row,parent,false);
            viewHolder= new CategorisedApplicationsAdapter.ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvApplicationName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Categorised_Apps_row);
            viewHolder.imageAppIcon= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Categorised_Apps_row);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder= (CategorisedApplicationsAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        String pName=packageNames.get(position);
        viewHolder.tvApplicationName.setText(getApplicationName(packageManager,pName));
        viewHolder.imageAppIcon.setImageDrawable( getApplicationIcon(packageManager,pName));
        viewHolder.packageName=pName;
        // view.setTag(categoryList.get(position).toString());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
   ViewHolder viewholder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                Intent launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(viewholder.packageName);
                if (launchIntent != null) {
                  mContext.startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

This is my code please check once.

Comment: @Kona_Suresh, thanks. I tried your code by adding String id in my holder but still no luck on it :(

Comment: you should follow the above code it should work. may be you are not adding the setTag(ViewHolder) and getTag(ViewHolder) methods for View.